# XCode 7.01 Crash on File Creation

Tags: ios, xcode, crash

I'm using OSX El Capitan and the latest version of XCode to develop an iOS application. Whenever I try to create a new file, XCode crashes after I press "Next" after I name the class. This has happened for every type of class I've tried creating except for Swift.

```
Here is the first part of the error report.

Process:               Xcode [4081]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               6.2 (6776)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-6776000000000000~11
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       811566096
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [4081]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2015-10-07 01:04:49.658 -0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11 (15A284)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        8CCC711A-6D41-8C93-1D5D-699FE67CA08C

Sleep/Wake UUID:       FC38EBBC-3DF3-4728-A20A-8477D6919684

Time Awake Since Boot: 1800 seconds
Time Since Wake:       62 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
Sending goNextOrFinish: to <IDEAssistantWindowController: 0x7fbf5ec43190> from <NSButton: 0x7fbf5ec38d10>
ProductBuildVersion: 6C131e
ASSERTION FAILURE in /SourceCache/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-6776/IDEKit/Assistants/IDECompletionDestinationManager.m:357
Details:  Assertion failed: [childItems count] == 1
Object:   <IDECompletionDestinationManager: 0x7fbf5cfc1050>
Method:   -workspaceNavigableItem
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fbf597038b0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   
  0: Sending goNextOrFinish: to <IDEAssistantWindowController: 0x7fbf5ec43190> from <NSButton: 0x7fbf5ec38d10>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess Xcode installation is not proper in your system. Just quit Xcode Reinstall it again.

Answer (score 0):

Quit Xcode and and reinstall from AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

My friend at work had to do a clean install to make it work properly (no restore from time machine), i didn't have any issue, and our iMac are equal in specs.

It could be direct related to alcatraz plugin's (if you use then), or software that was available in Yosemite and it's not working/properly upgraded to El Capitan